# strange padding in responsive image

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm try to implement bilboard with floated text. See the screenshot, please:

[image]

So, I wrote some code for this:

```
<div class="bilboard hcenter">
<div class="content">
    <div class="imwrap"><img src="img/dog.png" /></div>
    <span>WE'RE THE SAME PASSIONATE PEOPLE</span>
    <span>YOU KNOW AND LOVE</span>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
    div.hcenter {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.bilboard {
    max-width: 1100px;
    background-color: #cd1b31;
    min-height: 205px;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 20%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}

.bilboard .content {
    margin-top: -20%;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.bilboard .content img {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;}

.bilboard .imwrap {
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

If I resize my html in firefox and IE I see **the strange yellow padding at dog's left**:

[image]

In Chrome all is good.

What is it and where I'm wrong?
Or, maybe my way is stupid and code is simpliest? Can somebody help me to code it?

Yellow color is just for show problem. imwrap block has bigger width than img

Comment: Scammy link.....flagged

Comment: why?? this is screenshot - cloud!

Comment: The links aren't scammy, checked them out and it's just a foreign image uploader, not like the usual imgur or imageshack etc etc.

Comment: didn't take me to any screenshot. just a page with loads of ads, maybe my browsers blocking the content and letting the ads through ?? Doubt it  though and there are plenty of better place to show a screenshot without the shite.

Comment: The image he is talking about does look like an ad. The first link shows what he's trying to achieve with the wrapping etc. Look again

Comment: Removed my down vote for putting the images on here, I can now see that you do actually have a problem that you need StackOverflows members to help with and wasn't just trying to get a load of people to click a scammy link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading through your problem, i think it may be due to setting the height. Ive tested this out in the JSFiddle below and seems to work fine.

**HTML**

```
<div class="bilboard hcenter">
    <div class="content">
        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e2/Bon_toutou.png"/>
        <span>WE'RE THE SAME PASSIONATE PEOPLE</span>
        <span>YOU KNOW AND LOVE</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.hcenter {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.bilboard {
    max-width: 1100px;
    background-color: #cd1b31;
    min-height: 205px;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 20%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}

.bilboard .content {
    margin-top: -20%;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.bilboard .content img {
    max-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    float: right;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5okhq38q/4/)

Comment: jsfiddle can't show my problem.
if I use developer tools, imwrap bigger than image ... yellow color just for show ...

Comment: Have you tried the transparent method yet? See jsFiddle in answer.

Comment: http://imgur.com/6BevyIU this is problem ... the imgwrap class is bigger, color is not important ...

Comment: See fix above, its down to setting the height element, change it to auto and you should be fine.

Comment: it's broken my design ... http://imgur.com/GFvdhGU height of image does not responsive, imahe height too big ...

Comment: Add `max-height: 100%;` to the `.imwrap` class. shouldn't allow it to go to big now.

Comment: The wrapping block is fitted to parent, but image is still big : http://imgur.com/UwO7O12 ... i'm cry :(

Comment: Sod it, rejigged your code to make it nice, you really dont need the container round the img as its not doing a heck of alot. See amended code in next 2 mins

Comment: No problem :D. finally got there in the end, an upvote would be awesome too if possible <3

Comment: Thats fine :). Good luck with the rest of the project!